# Disable shorter line spacing on lines without ascenders/descenders (setmainfont)

Tags: fontspec, line-spacing

I'm using a system font with `fontspec`, and I'm using the `Scale` option when I declare it with `\setmainfont`.

I've found that whenever I use the `Scale` option, the line spacing is no longer consistent. If two consecutive lines have no ascenders or descenders, the spacing between them is very tight. If there's even one ascender/descender between two lines, the spacing is adjusted enough so that there's no overlap.

Is there any way to return to a consistent line spacing without having to sacrifice the `Scale` option?

Here's a visual example, and the code I used to produce it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\setmainfont[Scale=1.7]{HoeflerText-Roman}

\begin{document}
This is a test aaaa aaaa aaaa aa a aa aa aa a  a aa a aajaa a aaaaa a aaajaa aaa aaaa a  aaaa aa a  aa  a aaaAAAaaa a aa a  aa  a
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to make `\baselineskip` larger than the letters. using Scale=1.7 seems very odd, but `\linespread{2}` or whatever number you need, should avoid most of the problems.

Comment: What's odd about it? I picked that scale through trial and error, so I'm not to sure if there's a better way of solving my problem. Would it be better to set `\fontsize`? I'm trying to get the character length of the paragraphs to be close to 50-70 without sacrificing the page size and margins.

Comment: it would be _much_ better to change font size. scaling the font at that level is for small adjustments so that (say) a nominal 10pt roman font matches the nominal 10pt font you have chosen for sans serif.  using 1.7 means that whenever you ask for a 10pt one you get a 17pt one, so it never fits in the allotted space.

Comment: With that setting, the ascenders are about 11.86pt and the descenders are about 4.74pt, so you need a baselineskip of at least 18.6pt to have 2pt between ascenders and descenders, which means you should do `\linespread{1.55}` because 18.6/12=1.55 (12pt is the default baseline skip).

Comment: I tried with `\linespread{1.7}` and it seems a bit too much.

Comment: Would you also agree, @egreg, that in my situation it's better just to set a default point size for the document instead of scaling at 1.7 and setting a line spread of 1.55?

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley It depends on what kind of document you're doing; 55 characters per line seems really too short, but there's no hard and fast rule. A font at nominal size of 17pt is big in absolute terms; however, the lectionary we use in the church has a font at 24pt or perhaps more (and large pages, of course): again, it depends on the document you're preparing.

Comment: @egreg I'm preparing a signature to be made from four A4-sized folios. The TeX document is set with `a4paper`, so that it will scale properly when I impose four pages on a single sheet. I wanted the text to be as readable as possible, and it seems like a lot of designers claim that 50-70 characters per line is optimal for reading.

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley I'd suggest using `memoir` with its 17pt option.

Answer (score 8):

When scaling fonts you need to make sure that the interline spacing is big enough to hold the characters. Using scale in the font loading is intended to make small adjustments to tune different fonts so match in some way, perhaps making two different fonts have the same x-height when loaded at the same nominal size.

As it is every time you ask for a 10pt font (on a default 12pt baseline) you are substituting a 17pt font which does not fit, so tex can not preserve the even spacing at the specified 12pt `\baselineskip`, so it packs the lines as close as it can, separating them with `\lineskip` (1pt)

So you could increase the baseline spacing by, say, `\linespread{1.6}` but it would be more natural to specify a 17pt font.

In the default classes `\LARGE` is 17pt on a 22pt baseline, so you could just use that, however that just selects a large body font.

If you need a large size for all document elements, better to use a class with such a design option such as `memoir` or `extarticle` which have `17pt` option, or use the `12pt` option with an `a5paper` option, then scale by a5/a4 at the print/layout stage.

Answer (score 3):

TeX will automatically space out a line that has contains excessively ‘high’ material; consider a line that contains maths like

```
$\frac{\int_0^1 x dx}{\int_0^1 y dy}$
```

This is what you're seeing here, because your large font scaling has caused even regular letters to become ‘high’. David has already given a number of solutions to avoid this problem.

TeX also allows you to adjust the limit at which it inserts the extra padding using the register `\lineskiplimit`. As *TeX by Topic* describes, it is the ‘Distance to be maintained between the bottom and top of neighbouring boxes on a vertical list.’ (default `0pt`).

If this is made large and negative, then no extra space is inserted (but material in successive lines may well collide):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=1.7]{Times}
\lineskiplimit=-999pt\relax
\begin{document}
This is a test aaaa aaaa aaaa aa a aa aa aa a  a aa a  aajaa a aAAAaa a aaajaa aaa aaaa a  aaaa $\frac{\int_0^1 x dx}{\int_0^1 y dy}$ aa a  aa  a aaaAAAaaa a aa a  aa  a
\end{document}
```